# Word Macro for Ctrl +F

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba

Not sure if this is possible. 
I have a macro for highlighting a bunch of text. It basically automates the process of going through the advanced menu, pressing wild cards, entering my search and clicking highlight all.

1. I can press Ctrl +F to get a list of results. I want to automate thisn
2. My issue is that I can't find a way to open the navigation plane with results.
3. Their are a few ways to open the navigation plane it seems. But they all open a blank one for me. I don't know if I need to add something to the macro to get it to write.

Then you press Ctrl +F and the navigation plane has results.

```
    --------CODE TO HIGHLIGHT TARGET 1------------------- 
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "target1"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True 
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
    .Format = True 
    .MatchCase = True 
    .MatchWholeWord = False 
    .MatchWildcards = True 
    .MatchSoundsLike = False 
    .MatchAllWordForms = False 
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: This is the code I am using

Comment: ' --------CODE TO HIGHLIGHT TARGET 1-------------------
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "target1"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

Comment: End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controlling task panes such as the Navigation Pane is not possible with VBA. Task panes are not exposed in the Office Application Object Models.

There is a free Word add-in called **AuthorTec Find'n Highlight** and it has a built-in navigation function that allows you to go to each text element that was found and highlighted by the add-in.